# Virtualbox not found when installing Qt 5 emulator

Tags: virtualbox, qt

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu on Virtualbox virtual machine and emulator option was selected prior to installation and met with following error:

[image: Qt emulator installation error]

However I actually have Virtualbox installed on the host computer (Windows 10) and it seems that the Qt maintenance (running in Virtualbox virtual machine) is unable to detect Virtualbox running on the host PC (Windows).

Comment: Have you tried to install VirtualBox within your Ubuntu virtual machine?

Comment: not really, I can give it a shot though. but I guess previously I installed Qt in windows environment, that's why it can detect my virtualbox.